# Sonar plugin installation issue in eclipse helios for maven project

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, installation, sonarqube

I am using :

> **Eclipse Helios Version: 3.6.2 
>     Sonar Java Analyser 3.1.0.2**

**Steps followed during installation of sonar in eclipse :**

1. Help -> Install New Software
2. Url used for installation :  http://dist.sonar-ide.codehaus.org/eclipse
3. Restarted eclipse from cmd using : ecipse -clean

**PROBLEM** : 
Cannot find sonar in Windows->Preferences to configure.
Please help me resolve this issue.

Comment: do you have write access to your eclipse folder? you should not copy eclipe to "programm files" without admin rights allways on (and you should avoid this for sure).

Comment: Please update your question to detail your environment: version of Sonar, version of Eclipse, version of Java, ... And please format your question properly (i.e. do not write a single long line, use foramtting options).

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse Helios is only compatible with Sonar Eclipse 2.4.0, as you can see on the installation page: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Installing+Sonar+in+Eclipse

If you want to use the latest features of Sonar Eclipse (3.1), then you should upgrade your Eclipse installation to at least Indigo (3.7.x).